# Click on datagridview and show the values from database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` with columns  Name, Surname, CardNumber those fields are from connected database which has a lot more values.

Now when i click on one row in `datagridview` it should open me Form2.  On form2 i have all fields/textboxes from database and it should fill them by the clicked value.

Example: In `datagridview` i have name StackGuru  . When i click on that name it should open me form2 with all of information about that name.

I hope i explained a bit

Comment: What have you got so far... show some code.

Comment: I only have the form design. And on form load event it show he first value in it.

Answer (score 0):

your description lacks a lot of information

but assuming you have form1 with a datagridview

and form2 with some textboxes then if the binding is already applied with a dataset/tableadapter etc.

on form2 you should have something like

```
Private myfilter As String = Nothing

Public Sub New(filter As String)
    InitializeComponent()

    Me.myfilter = filter
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Not myfilter = Nothing Then
        fillFilterForm1()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub fillFilterForm1()
    Me.MyFilterTableAdapter.FillBy(Me.MyDataSet._MyFilter, Me.myfilter)
End Sub
```

in your Dataset you have to add a new query to the desired table with a parameter like

```
where myColumn = @myFilter
```

and on form1 you should have something like this

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick
    Dim f2 As New Form2(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("MyFilterColumn").Value.ToString)
    f2.Show()
End Sub
```

then it should work

another approach would be to reference Form1 on Form2